# How to link the events of a search used as an alert in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a query that I created that looks like this:

```
index="someindex" Level=Error | rex field=_raw "\"Exception\":\"(?<ExceptionType>.*?):" 
| eval ExceptionType = if(isnull(ExceptionType), "Custom log",ExceptionType) | search ExceptionType="Custom log"
```

And I saved it as an alert that sends a message to Slack that looks like this:
[image]

Here's the problem. When I run this search normally I get the results like so:

[image]

And I can click on the "events" tab to see the individual events that are aggregated by the "stats" command.
However, when I click the link generated by the alert, I only get the aggregated results. I can't view the individual events. So my question is: is there any way to create a link that will allow to expand the events from which the results are aggregated?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the "eventstats" command was exactly what I needed.